# Regex: Select all lines that do not contain some particular words in front of another particular words (tags)

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to find a regex formula as to select all line that does not have `<p class="test_formal">` in front of `<span class="test_formal2">`

`<p class="test_formal"><span class="test_formal2">`

I made a regex, but is not too good.

`(?s)\A(?!.*?(?<!\w)(<span class="test_formal2">)(?!\w)<p class="test_formal">).*`

Can anyone help me a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match all lines that have:

`<span class="test_formal2">` followed or not by `<p class="test_formal">`

But not `<p class="test_formal">` followed by `<span class="test_formal2">`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:(?!<p class="test_formal">).)*<span class="test_formal2">.*$`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                               # beginning of line
  (?:                           # start non capture group
    (?!                         # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't
      <p class="test_formal">   # literally
    )                           # end lookahead
    .                           # 1 any character
  )*                            # end group, may appear 0 or more times
  <span class="test_formal2">   # literally
  .*                            # 0 or more any character
$                               # end of line
```

**Given:**

```
<p class="test_formal">
<span class="test_formal2">
<p class="test_formal"><span class="test_formal2">
blah blah <p class="test_formal"><span class="test_formal2"> blah blah
<span class="test_formal2"><p class="test_formal">
blah blah <span class="test_formal2"><p class="test_formal"> blah blah
```

**It matches:**

```
Search "^(?:(?!<p class="test_formal">).)*<span class="test_formal2">.*$" (3 hits in 1 file)
  new 2 (3 hits)
    Line 2: <span class="test_formal2">
    Line 5: <span class="test_formal2"><p class="test_formal">
    Line 6: blah blah <span class="test_formal2"><p class="test_formal"> blah blah
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YEcK8e/3)

Comment: thank you, Toto. But there is a small problem. The regex should find only those line which necessarily contain  `<span class="test_formal2">` . So, your regex selects inverse, first of all those line that contains <p class="test_formal">. See this update  https://regex101.com/r/YEcK8e/2

Comment: ok, I find the problem. Update a little bit your regex, just add `!` in fist paranthesis, right before  `<p class="test_formal">`. Works. So, please update your regex answer with this  `^(?:(?:.*?!<p class="test_formal">(?:(?!<span class="test_formal2">).)*)|(?:(?!<p class="test_formal">).)*<span class="test_formal2">.*)$`

Comment: @RobRob: That wasn't clear. I've completely rewrite the regex, it's now really simplifed.